# Jupyter Notebook's terminal command not using correct conda environment

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda

I have 2 conda environments installed:
- `env1`: base environment where jupyter-notebook is installed and started from
- `env2`: project environment with ipykernel installed
I manually added kernelspecs for the 2 environments following [this](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html#kernels-for-different-environments) guide.

Everything works fine. `sys.executable` in 2 kernels show separate, correct paths.  But for terminal commands (i.e. `!which python`), no matter which kernel I'm running in the environment defaults to `env1`.

Is there any way to have the notebook automatically change this to the kernel's environment?

P.S. I already tried installing nb_conda, nb_conda_kernels

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly, but maybe this Q&A helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58068818/how-to-use-jupyter-notebooks-in-a-conda-environment

Answer (score 1):

install nb_conda and nb_conda_kernels into your base.

```
conda install nb_conda nb_conda_kernels -n env1
```

This should give you the ability to change kernel in jupyter, and use the env2 kernel.

Comment: This does not work. In fact I already had these 2 packages from before.

Comment: Can you try listing kernelspecs? jupyter kernelspec list

Comment: python3           /home/ec2-user/miniconda3/envs/airflow3/lib/python3.6/site-p                                                                                                             ackages/ipykernel/resources  |


airflow3          /home/ec2-user/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/airflow3  | 


data_interface    /home/ec2-user/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/data_interface

Answer (score 0):

I would install jupyter notebook in the base env (not env1, not env2)
Then install nb_conda_kernels in the base

in env1 and env2, install ipykernel
in env1 and env2, run this:

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name env1 --display-name "env1 env"
```

Check this out for more info:
[New Conda environment with latest Python Version for Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74611535/new-conda-environment-with-latest-python-version-for-jupyter-notebook)